# Responsive button - With name and number

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I tried to create a corresponding button that contains the name of the button and a number.

I used padding to separate the button name from the number, however when the number is very high, that same number overlaps the button name.

Is there a way to center the name on the button and make the button fully responsive regardless of the number displayed?

**[DEMO](https://www.codeply.com/p/BF89uHpB0k)**

**Html**

```
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-md-center flex-nowrap" style="margin-top:50px">
    <a style="color: #51CC8B;" class="btnP">Prepared
      <span class="nav-link btn-glyphicon1">1500</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

**Css**

```
.btnP {
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  height: 24px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 6px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #51CC8B;
  -ms-border-radius: 16px;
  -o-border-radius: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border-width: none;
  background: #EDFAF3;
  outline: none;
}

.btn-glyphicon1 { 
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 16px;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #DDF6E9 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #51CC8B;
}
```

[image]

**PROBLEM**

[image]

As you can see in the image, the number overlaps the name :( I want the text to always remain centered on the button and the width to adjust according to the size of the number.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.btnP {
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  height: 24px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  margin-right: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 6px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #51CC8B;
  -ms-border-radius: 16px;
  -o-border-radius: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border-width: none;
  background: #EDFAF3;
  outline: none;

}

.btn-glyphicon1 { 
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 6px;
  
  border-radius: 16px;
  
  align-items:center;
  background: #DDF6E9 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-left:20px;
  color: #51CC8B;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-md-center flex-nowrap" style="margin-top:50px">
    <a style="color: #51CC8B;" class="btnP">Prepared
      <span class="nav-link btn-glyphicon1">1500</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !